# How to increase the inside circle's size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have done the following CSS with JQuery:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/3gjwvya6/1/) 
However I don't know why I cannot increase the width and height of the green circle in a way which is a little greater than the gray circle (which I call it the main circle) with a lower z-index, in a way that by passing the time, the green circle shows the progress around the main cirecle(just on the border of gray circle because I use a lower z-index for green cirecle)

Green circle is:

```
<div  id='timer'></div>
```

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/3gjwvya6/2/ ? Just played around with some font sizes, positioning, and paddings/margins.

Comment: No I need the green circle be a little bit larger than the the dark gray circle with a lower-index, so it just shows like a border around dark gray circle, did I explain clearly? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
div.slice{
    font-size: 70px !important;
    margin-left: -26px;
    margin-top: -21px;
}
```

Comment: At least it is not working for me! Can you show me in JSfiddle please?

Comment: But thats not what I was looking for! I want the green circle be larger than gray circle with lower z-index

Comment: It is near! But I want the green circle to be larger than the gray one! with a lower z-index; so it should show the progress around the gray circle!

Comment: just play with margin-left, margin-top and font-size to get exactly what you want.

Comment: For some reason when I increase font-size and then align the margin top and left, it cuts off the green circle!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `font-size` on the `#timer` div to get the circle to actually increase in size. However the positioning will still be off because your bottom circle border is throwing off the timer positioning so you will need to play with the margin on the #timer to get it directly positioned over the btn.